# Is my content indexed by Google when I use tinyMCE in my website

Tags: iframe, indexing, tinymce, search-engine

I have website with a lot of tinyMCE instances. I am wondering is that a problem for Google robots to index my content because inside the iframes there is a lot of valuable information. If this information is not indexed it will be bad impact to my page rank and appearing in top results when someone perform search will be impossible!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want google to index your files, or want to change how it crawls your site, edit your server's robots.txt. Info on how to configure it [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)